# 7 picture doesn't generate images emidiatly

Tags: media

I have a site with picture installed. When a user access the site with a device where image styles are not created yet the user has too refresh the site to see the image. How could I force the theme to preprocess the image styles when cronies runs?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Thereisnothing related to this.